# How to implement multiple query condition with Spring Data MongDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I'm starting learn spring data mongodb. Currently, I try to implement multiple condition query with Spring Data MongoDB.

First I have a sample collection

```
{
    "_id": "df05532f-8893-4802-8710-ab92056c9c77",
    "objectId": {
      "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "creator": {
      "_id": {
        "$numberLong": "3"
      },
      "username": "magic"
    },
    "content": "7878787887",
    "attachments": [],
    "pinned": false,
    "histories": [
      {
        "content": "new new comment 2222",
        "createdAt": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1664970753576"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "content": "update me",
        "createdAt": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1664970753691"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "content": "update me3333",
        "createdAt": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1664970753734"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "content": "44444455666",
        "createdAt": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1664970753740"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "contentUpdateAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1664970753745"
      }
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1664970753576"
      }
    },
    "lastModifiedAt": {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "1664970753772"
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to find a partial document when the `array histories` has one element that matched with `content` equals `44444455666`

With MongoDB CLI, I completed build the query like

```
db.ticket_detail_comments.find(
    {
        histories: {
            $elemMatch: {
                content: "44444455666"
            }
        },
        _id : "df05532f-8893-4802-8710-ab92056c9c77"
    },
    { "histories.$": 1, name: 1 }
)
```

The result was exactly what I expected

```
{
    "_id": "df05532f-8893-4802-8710-ab92056c9c77",
    "histories": [
        {
            "content": "44444455666",
            "createdAt": {
                "$date": {
                    "$numberLong": "1664970753740"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I tried to build query with Spring Data MongoDB (using MongoDbTemplate) I can't find any way to build query look like in console. I tried addOperation but seem not work,

I tried to build 2 separated Criteria (one, two) that match with 2 condition I expected, then combine them with andOperation like `new Criteria().andOperator(one).andOperator(two);`. The unhappy part is the query generated is so different

```
db.ticket_detail_comments.find(
    {
        "$and": [
            {
                histories: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        content: "44444455666"
                    }
                },
                _id : "df05532f-8893-4802-8710-ab92056c9c77"
            },
            { "histories.$": 1, name: 1 }
        ]
    }
)
```

With this query, I always get a null value. Can anyone help me with that? What is correct Criteria syntax I should use?

Thanks for reading.

---

UPDATE
I created a small demo, let's see

Data in Mongo Collection look like

```
{
  "_id": "dad9db98-241b-40fa-aab4-af1671f97631",
  "data": "demo",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "tim",
      "age": 19
    },
    {
      "name": "alex",
      "age": 18
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.example.demo.Data"
}
```

MONGOCLI

```
db.data.find(
    {
        children: {
            $elemMatch: {
                name: "alex"
            }
        },
        _id : "dad9db98-241b-40fa-aab4-af1671f97631"
    },
    { "children.$": 1}
)
```

=> Result:

```
{ _id: 'dad9db98-241b-40fa-aab4-af1671f97631',
  children: [ { name: 'alex', age: 18 } ] }
```

JAVA CODE

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private final MongoTemplate template;

    public DemoApplication(MongoTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Data.Child child1 = Data.Child.builder()
                .name("alex")
                .age(18)
                .build();

        Data.Child child2 = Data.Child.builder()
                .name("tim")
                .age(19)
                .build();
        final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Data data = Data.builder()
                .id(id)
                .data("demo")
                .children(List.of(child2, child1))
                .build();


        template.save(data, "data");
        Query query = Query.query(
                Criteria.where("_id").is(id).and("children")
                        .elemMatch(Criteria.where("name").is("alex"))
        );
        query.fields().position("children", 1);
        var r = template.findOne(query, Data.class, "data");
        System.out.printf("DEBUG");
    }

}

@lombok.Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class Data {

    private String id;

    private String data;

    private List<Child> children;

    @lombok.Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    static class Child {
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
    }
}
```

=> Result: **Data Object with 2 elements in children list.**

But what I expected is Data Object has one element in children list like resut from CLI

Comment: why projection query is inside `$and` condition `{ "histories.$": 1, name: 1 }`?

Comment: You give me a good suggestion, it seems I put all condition in criteria, not projection. I will try again

Comment: share the actual criteria query you are using

Comment: I updated the sample. Could you take a look?

Comment: Sorry it worked.

Comment: Your keywork really saved my day